# How to play song using SoundCloud API

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, soundcloud

I am trying to make a music player that works with SoundCloud. So I have buttons like play, next, prev. and I made functions like:

```
function playIt(){
 SC.stream("/tracks/293", function(sound){
   sound.play();
 });
}
```

So it plays song when the button is player:

```
<button onclick="playIt()">Play</button>
```

But it does not work. Any idea?
Here is the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zcN7G/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1º - Put the JS files in the head. Use the "External Resources" on JSfiddle.

2º - Put `var sound` = [...] before the `SC.steam`.

Is that.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/don/zcN7G/3/

Comment: Thank you os much. Can you please explain what does sound variable do? I m just not getting it. But its working and Thanks for that.

Comment: You are using the `sound.play()` to play the music, you need to put the variable sound to determine what will be played.

Answer (score 0):

According to *@lago* above, let me deliver a full short code, so you can do your own labs ;-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src=http://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk.js></script>
<script>
SC.initialize({client_id:'your client_id goes here'});    
function p()
       {
       SC.stream
               (
              '/tracks/293',
               function(s)
                       {
                       s.play()
                       }
               )
       }
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<button onclick=p()>play</button>
</body>
</html>
```

API guide [here](https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide)